# How do I do different maxlengths for different text fields?

Tags: textfield, maxlength

I have an options panel in my WordPress theme with several text fields e.g. project title, project description, etc.

```
case 'text':
        $val = $value['std'];
        $std = get_option($value['id']);
        if ( $std != "") { $val = $std; }
        $output .= '<input class="" maxlength="12" name=""'. $value['id'] .'" id="'. $value['id'] .'" type="'. $value['type'] .'" value="'. $val .'" />';
    break;
```

As the above code shows... I currently have my max length for the text fields as 12, but I would like to have a max length to be different for each of the text fields. How can I do this?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code where you define the input name.
You have an extra quote " here: name=" " '. $value['id'].' ", this should be name=" '. $value['id'].' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an array containing the fields and their corresponding maxlength values.
(I've used field names, but you could also use an Id number)

*E.g:* field_name => max_length_for_that_field

```
$maxFieldLengths = array(
    'project_title' => 12,   //project title has 12 max length
    'project_description' => 100   //project description has 100 max length
);
```

Identify which text field (input) you are currently building and use that identifier to reference your maxFieldLengths array.

```
case 'text':
    ...
    $field_name = // Identify the current field here;
    $output .= '<input class="" maxlength="'. $maxFieldLengths[$field_name] .'" etc .....' />
break;
```

---

Note: From your code sample it's not 100% clear how you identify the field you are currently building.  You could, for example, use something like:

```
...
$field_name = getFieldFromId($value['id']);
```